# How to store OAuth1 tokens used by an Angular Front-End

Tags: angular, security, headless, oauth-1.0a

I'm currently working on a headless project: an Angular Front-End retrieves data dynamically using a Back-End's API.

This API requires an OAuth1 ahtorization, so that the Angular app has to pass 4 tokens (request, request secret, access, access secret) on each call.

Currently, these tokens are stored in a JS config file. As the API client is a pure Front-End app, any user can access them (even from the browser's console!).

My question is pretty obvious: how to store these tokens in a more secure way in my use case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your Angular version?

Comment: I'm using Angular 7

Comment: You can save them in JSON file and read them with service,
or you just can store them encrypted in localstorage.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. Indeed, I already thought about such a strategy. I think it's useless, because the encoding/decoding functions would been visible by anyone, since it's part of the front-end app...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can encode each token and store it in localstorage, when you need to send the token the back end retrieve it from localstorage decode it and send it back.

Comment: Thank you Ali. Indeed, I already thought about such a strategy. I think it's useless, because the encoding/decoding functions would been visible by anyone, since it's part of the front-end app...

Answer (score 0):

save in Local Storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: name }));
```

get from Local Storage:

```
var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
var token = currentUser.token; // your token
```